Crontab with proxy
I have an issue :
I add inside /etc/profile.d/proxy :
export http_proxy=http://IP:80/
export https_proxy=http://IP:80/
export ftp_proxy=http://IP:80/
export no_proxy="localhost,127.0.0.1,localaddress,.domain.com"
export HTTP_PROXY=http://IP:80/
export HTTPS_PROXY=http://IP:80/
export FTP_PROXY=http://IP:80/
export NO_PROXY="localhost,127.0.0.1,localaddress,.domain.com"
Run source /etc/profile.d/proxy.sh
Then :

run a script with /usr/bin/php /var/cron/script.php : perfect :)
add inside crontab -e : sudo /usr/bin/php /var/cron/supervision.php : nothing :(

According to how to add http_proxy automatically to new users in ubuntu server it should be enough. It was chmod 755 (root:root).
My cron, as root, just refuse to use it.

AFAIK cron doesn't run jobs inside a login shell, so doesn't source /etc/profile (nor, by extension, *.sh files in /etc/profile.d/)

I just put the proxy inside /etc/environment...problem solved.
